# Difference between Google NFC API an Open NFC API

Tags: java, android, nfc, open-nfc

I got my Nexus S and now i plan to start playing with NFC. Which API should i use, Google NFC API([Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html) or Open NFC ([Link](http://www.open-nfc.org/opennfc_library/overview-summary.html))?

Besides reading and writing tags, i am interested in card emulation, so i could use my phone to open my doors which use simple tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the Google NFC API atm unless you create a custom build of android to enable more functionality of the NFC chip. If you want to enable card emulation you'll have to go the custom build route.

In the future Google may open up more functionality in their API...

Comment: With custom build you mean rooting my phone or creating my own ROM?

Comment: Yes, you'll build the Android sources with the customizations you need and then place it on your phone.